# Unable to edit database entry

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So I have this application, where you create a user and then you can add movies and shows into a database. Like a bad version on IMDB?

Now.. I have this controller: https://github.com/Veske/form/blob/ryhm/app/controllers/movies_controller.rb

I have set up routes for movies and also it has all the necessary view files.. but when I attempt to go on a page to edit one of the movies: http://whatever.com/shows/1/edit for example, it gives me a error:

```
Couldn't find User with id=1

 def correct_user
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    redirect_to root_url unless current_user?(@user)
  end
end

params
{"id"=>"1"}
```

Now.. why is it thinking that the param I throw at it, is a @user param when I have a update  and edit controller made specially for Movies?

Comment: posting your routes would give us better understanding of the error. Nevertheless, have you tried using resources in your routes? like resources :shows #this will generate the http://whatever.com/shows/1/edit

Comment: You can navigate through the repo to the routes, downvote not needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't seem to understand [routes](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html). The context in which you are using `params[:id]` is the movies controller, hence, the id would be the movie id. At the same time, you're authenticating (?) with the same param, giving you the error.

For basic authentication you could use the session hash, and for a more advanced one there are lots of gems, being devise the most popular.

PS: use `rake routes` to check your available routes and its URL params.

Comment: I am using a resources :movies for movies. I got everything fixed now but now it gives me a error that No route matches [POST] "/movies/1/edit".   But the resources should give me all routes for movies? Why is that.

Comment: Glad it helped. Be sure to check rails docs http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html (its the same posted above). Every time you want to solve something check for gems and libraries first, there's no need to reinvent the wheel. (Your route missing problem might be from a faulty submit button as the edit action gives you the form and the post to "movies/1" goes to update.  Check rake routes again, and you'll see.

Answer (score 1):

This is a `MoviesController`, so the `params[:id]` is actually the `movie_id`, i.e., the number "1" in your url "http://whatever.com/shows/1/edit". Not the `user_id`. So it throws the exception at line `@user = User.find(params[:id])`.

I went through your code but can't find where the correct `user_id` should come from. The `Movie` model doesn't `belongs_to user`. You should check out where the `user` come from.

Answer (score 1):

Your `shows_controller.rb` file calls `correct_user` before running the edit action you are calling, and it is specifically looking for a user on line 70.  So it would make sense that you are getting this error if there is no user with an ID of 1.

Answer (score 1):

**Why is it thinking that the param I throw at it, is a @user param when I have a update and edit controller made specially for Movies?**

Because you have a before_action filter at the top of your controller that is being called on the edit action.

You get into the `correct_user` method, which is using finding a user based on `params[:id]` .  To test that this is your actual problem, you might want to try to change line 68 in your controller to:

```
@user = User.last #quick fix
```

The above could be used as a quick fix -you shouldn't get that error you posted about any more, as long as your user is signed in.  If this allows you to avoid the error, you then need to concern yourself with properly assigning this `User#id` value when this `correct_user` method is called by your controller.

Comment: Well it solves the error yes but it will redirect me to root url as the page I want to access is only for logged in users, but with this change it does not aknowlage it anymore.

Comment: Ok, then you need to properly assign the values for the user and the shows item you want to edit.  What parameter holds the user id?

Comment: I actually ended up deleteing the def correct_user
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    
I did not actually need it, did not realize it before. But this fixed the whole problem. Now I have a new one with routes..